# AVR - Timer0 is not firing if INT5 is enabled in EIMSK

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

I'm using an **[ATMEGA2560](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf)**.

Compiler: **avr-gcc (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.4.5_1522) 4.8.1**

I have setup *TIMER0* for periodic tasks:

```
// Initialize Timer0
TCCR0A = (1<<WGM01); //CTC - mode 2
TCCR0B = (1<<CS01); //Prescale by 8
OCR0A  = (F_CPU / F_INTERRUPTS_SMALL / 8 - 1);// //~15kHz by default
TIMSK0 = (1<<OCIE0A);
```

This way I can have an ISR of (*TIMER0_COMPA_vect*):

```
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {...}
```

All of the above works fine until I enable the *INT5* external interrupt:

```
// From datasheet Table 15-3: 
// "The low level of INTn generates an interrupt request"
DDRE &= ~(1<<PE5);
EICRB &= ~(1<<ISC50);
EICRB &= ~(1<<ISC51);
EIMSK |= (1<<INT5);
```

When I enable *INT5*, the *Timer0* calls the ISR(*TIMER0_COMPA_vect*) only when *PE5* is **high**.

If PE5 is low, Timer0 **stops** and when PE5 goes high again, Timer0 continues.

Why do these modules are correlating like this? They need to be independent, no?

Comment: If I comment out the "EIMSK |= (1<<INT5)" line, Timer0 comes back to work fine again.

Comment: EIMSK is for EXTERNAL interrupts, only!

Comment: Scott, what do you mean? I want to use INT5 as external interrupt and also Timer0.

Comment: Are you getting stuck in the ISR for the external interrupt?

Comment: No, I don't think so, because the ISR currently does not do anything (just sets a variable based on PE5's value).

Comment: @evildemonic: Can it cause a stuck?

Comment: If you don't leave the ISR for the ext. interrupt, the other ISR will never run.

Comment: oh, I see now, you have a bigger problem...Interrupt priority.  The external interrupts have a higher priority than the timer ones.  Meaning, the pin going low will always 'take over' and not give a chance for the timer based interrupt to get serviced.  You might be able to work around this by turning on and off the ext. interrupt appropriately.

Comment: @evildemonic: wow. Thanks. I did not even think of the priorities and also thought that level interrupt will fire once then pin needs to be high again before the next ISR. Anyway thanks for the light!

Comment: @Daniel I'm glad I could help.  If you want that behavior, use the falling edge type interrupt:  `EICRB |= (1<<ISC51)` instead of `EICRB &= ~(1<<ISC51)`

Comment: Falling edge on INT5 won't wake up from powerdown sleep and I need that, but I did not mention this earlier. The part which I was missing is located on the 109th page of the datasheet: "When the external
interrupt is enabled and is configured as level triggered, the interrupt will trigger as long as the pin is held low."

Comment: @Daniel Are you stuck with INT5?  INT3 and lower can use pin change interrupts to wake from power-down.  Only INT4 and up are limited to level interrupts.

Comment: @evildemonic unfortunately all pins below INT5 are occupied for something else. (Dedicated functions: I2C and UART1). So only INT4..7 is usable for this purpose. But I can disable the level interrupt in the ISR and then it won't be fired until I re-enable.